# installing pptpd on ubuntu ec2

Tags: 12.04, permissions, vpn, amazon-ec2

I am running this line in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install pptpd
```

and here's the output I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bcrelay
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcrelay pptpd
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 96.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 446 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main bcrelay amd64 1.3.4-3ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main pptpd amd64 1.3.4-3ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pptpd/bcrelay_1.3.4-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pptpd/pptpd_1.3.4-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

what am i doing wrong? is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try again.. looks like a temporary problem - or change your Ubuntu Mirror (just remove us-west-1.ec2. from your /etc/apt/sources.list lines) and run sudo apt-get update.